# Run same Jmeter thread group after certain interval

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the same thread group after a certain interval. Example - 
JMeter will run thread group A and execute all http requests inside it and let's say for example after 20 sec it will run thread group A again and this loop should carry on until I manually stop the script.

What I have designed right now is something like this-

```
Thread Group A
     While Controller (I gave some condition so that it is always true) 
       Http request 1
       Http request 2
       Constant timer (20sec)
```

but this only puts 20sec delay between each http call.

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace Constant Timer with the [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler, keep all defaults and set "Duration" to `20000` milliseconds
2. Add [Syncrhonizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the Test Action sampler and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to be equal to the number of threads in your Thread Group
3. That's it, synchronizing timer will act as a "rendezvous" point so all your virtual users meet there and wait for 20 seconds together.

You might also be interested in [How to Easily Implement Pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter) in order to be able to configure more complex delay scenarios